# finding a list stored in dataframe cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` like this:

```
    values
0    [0,1]
1    [1,2]
2    [2,3]
3    [3,4]
4    [4,5]
```

Something like this doesn't work:

```
df[df['values'] == [0,1]]
```

I get:

```
ValueError: 'Lengths must match to compare', (5,), (2,)
```

How can I get a row given the `list` stored in that row?

Comment: what exactly is `a` here?

Comment: I intended to say something generic, like a string, a number, etc

Comment: is it a list, or is it one of the values in the list, give us an example.

Comment: ok, example  given

Comment: `df[df['values'] == '[0,1]']` Are the cells in list format? Why don't you try a string search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehenion:

```
[i == [0,1] for i in df['values']]
```

Like this:

```
df[[i == [0,1] for i in df['values']]]
```

Output:

```
   values
0  [0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[(df['values'].apply(pd.Series) == [0,1]).all(axis=1)]
```